# I want to use ASP.Net Web form master page in MVC views

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, webforms

I am able to add MVC in my Web form project. From here on wards we have decided to develop new pages in MVC. 
Now I want to use master page used in web form into the MVC views.

How I am able to apply web form master page to the MVC view page?

I am using visual studio 2019.

Comment: for MVC you want to use the `_Layout.cshtml` file as your master page in `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. You use `@RenderBody` for your content placeholder in the layout file

Comment: Helpful link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/layouts-master-pages-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0-part-fourteen/

Comment: I already have a master page "Site.Master". This master page is in old asp.net web form. I have added MVC in this web form application. Now, I want to use this master page(Site.Master) in MVC views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use from ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
and @RenderBody is Body of your form 
_Layou.cshtml is the same with web form master page.
GoodLuck!

Comment: I already have a master page "Site.Master". This master page is in old asp.net web form. I have added MVC in this web form application.
Now, I want to use this master page(Site.Master) in MVC views.

Comment: You can't. You will have to convert the Master Page to a shared Layout cshtml